# How to pause in between batches when iterating over a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to insert a pause (~30 sec) in between each batch when iterating over a dictionary.

When I insert sleep(seconds), it pauses in between each record.  I want it to pause in between each batch (i.e., after 5 records have been processed)

The code I have developed so far is this:

```
def chunked (dictionary, size):
    dictionary = iter(dictionary)
    while True:
        p = tuple(itertools.islice(dictionary,size))
        if not p:
            break
        yield p


for chunk in chunked(x.items(), 5):

    #1. Return zipcode of listing
    for ID, coordinates in x.items():

        geolocator = Nominatim()

        try:
            # approx. listing address based on latitude, longitude
            location = geolocator.reverse(coordinates, timeout=None)

            print(ID)
            print(location)

            sleep(30)
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Is there a better way?

Comment: Try decreasing the indent on your sleep function by two levels, so that it is contained only in your outer for loop.

Comment: I believe @rp372 is right, if you want to stop every 5 items ( a batch) you should `sleep(30)` after every chunk. Otherwise, you will be stopping at each element of that yielded batch (make sure you know what Generators are)

Answer (score 0):

As some users point out, try reducing the indentation of your `sleep(30)` by two levels, like this:

```
for chunk in chunked(x.items(), 5):

    #1. Return zipcode of listing
    for ID, coordinates in x.items():

        geolocator = Nominatim()

        try:
            # approx. listing address based on latitude, longitude
            location = geolocator.reverse(coordinates, timeout=None)

            print(ID)
            print(location)

    sleep(30)
```

With this, you will be pausing at each yielded batch you get from the generator, instead of pausing at each element of the batch.